# Programming NFC tags using TagWriter - can't write data on my tag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

Unfortunately I have problem with programming one of my NFC tags in TagWriter on android device. I getting message like that: "This item is used, blocked or not supported and cannot contain an NFC data set".

When I scanning tag with TagInfo application, I getting:

```
** TagInfo scan (version 2.00) 2013-07-15 10:50:31 **

-- INFO ------------------------------

# IC manufacturer:
Unknown manufacturer

# IC type:
Unknown IC

-- NDEF ------------------------------

# No NFC data set storage:

-- EXTRA ------------------------------

-- TECH ------------------------------

# Technologies supported:
ISO/IEC 14443-3 (Type A) compatible
ISO/IEC 14443-2 (Type A) compatible

# Android technology information:
Tag description:
* TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcA]
android.nfc.tech.NfcA
* Maximum transceive length: 253 bytes
* Default maximum transceive time-out: 1000 ms
MIFARE Classic support present in Android

# Detailed protocol information:
ID: 02:56:56:01
ATQA: 0x0400
SAK: 0x08
--------------------------------------
```

I am new in NFC technology, so I have problem with diagnose the problem, maybe you can tell me where is the problem? In android technology information section for this tag I have only one class: android.nfc.tech.NfcA. For tag with I working earlier (and who works fine) I have android.nfc.tech.Ndef and android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight classes too, so maybe there is the problem? How I can write this tag with TagWriter? Or it's impossible? If yes, how I can do that on another way? I need to write simple URL on tag.

Thanks for any help

Comment: From the SAK and ATQA data, it looks like the tag is a MIFARE Classic 1K tag. Your device claims to support MIFARE Classic tags, but Android does not provide the `MifareClassic` class in the technology list. This is strange... What type of Android device are you using and what Android version is it running?